# How does dynamic square bracket array initialization work in C?

Tags: c, dynamic-memory-allocation

I was quite surprised to find that the following code does work as one (beginner) would expect (Well I expected it to either fail to compile or segfault):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    int count = rand() % 1024 + 2;
    int arr[count];
    arr[count-1] = 3;
    for(int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
    {
        arr[i] = i * 3;
    }
    printf("%d %d %d", count - 1, arr[0], arr[count-1]);
    return 0;
}
```

To my surprise this [compiles, and works](https://ideone.com/OZ90ut).

I did not know it is possible to dynamically allocate an array by using square brackets, how does this work? I expected any kind of error stating that dynamic allocation using `[]` isn't allowed or possible in C.

How does this work?

Comment: C99 added Variable Length Arrays so this is fine

Comment: Oh that explains it, I didn't know the wording to search for, "variable" didn't come to my mind :) now I can find more information on this, thanks!

Comment: that's what duplicates are for. For people not knowing the terminology. All right in that case.

Comment: The answer that is used for the "duplicated" state describes the difference between heap and stack data. But it doesn't answer this question: `allocate an array by using square brackets, how does this work?`